# Android - Set onEditListener for all EditTexts under a parent

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener

Is there any easy way to set onEditListener to all EditTexts under a parent instead of making them one by one?
My idea is to show a save button only when the users change their profile info on EditTexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, you can call this recursion in `onCreateView()` if parent is fragment or `onCreate()` if parent is activity:

```
private static void enumLayout(LinearLayout ll) {
        int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++){
            View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof LinearLayout) {
                enumLayout((LinearLayout) v);
            } else if (v instance of EditText) {
                // set listener here
            }
        }
}
```

ll is root layout in your fragment/activity.